# How to pass a file path as a command line argument?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to run a script with a parameter (more precisely, pass a file to the script as an argument for processing). **For example: node script.js /root/file.log**. I have a script that parses logs and through process.argv () I pass an argument to it, but the result is not satisfactory. Instead of parsed code, I get `{sourcefile: 'file.log', destinationfile: undefined}`.
It feels like the process.argv() method does not accept the file as an argument and does not read it accordingly.

```
let srcFile = process.argv[2];
const fs = require('fs')
//const src = './file.log'
var file = fs.readFileSync(srcFile, 'utf8');
const startString = 'DisplayProgressbar: Building Gradle project';
const endString = 'BUILD FAILED';
var res = ''
var startIndex = file.indexOf(startString);

while(startIndex > -1) {

    let start = startIndex + startString.length;

    let end = file.indexOf(endString, start);

    res = file.slice(start, end);

    startIndex = file.indexOf(startString, end + endString.length);
}
console.log(res)
```

internal/fs/utils.js:612
throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(propName, ['string', 'Buffer', 'URL'], path);
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you may be better off using something like commander: https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander. This will allow you to run terminal commands.

Comment: For cli apps you should use a tool/lib like commander or in this case better (in my opinion) minimist.

Comment: As I understand it, that should work just fine. What is the problem / error? What does `console.log(file)` return? Maybe paths are incorrect or you got no permissions?

Comment: @FlashThunder In this case result is `{ sourcefile: 'file.log', destinationfile: undefined }`. But if i will clean `process.argv()` then the output will give me a piece of code that I parse.

Comment: Use dash before the file name. node script.js -/root/file.log

Comment: @Mr. `script.js <source file> [destination file]`

`Not enough non-option arguments: got 0, need at least 1`